# Arduino ESP8266 01 MQTT Raspberry pi

Tags: mqtt

I want to use ESP 8266 01 and arduino uno as client in MQTT. The code For ESP8266 01 is successfully compiled and I'M getting errors in Arduino uno
The error is 'messageTemp' was not declared in this scope

Amd also I have a thought of using stm32xx in client.
If I compile for that

exit status 1

ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

above is the error I'm getting

1)ESP code

```
 // Loading the ESP8266WiFi library and the PubSubClient library
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

 // Change the credentials below, so your ESP8266 connects to your router
const char* ssid = "YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
const char* mqtt_server = "YOUR_RPi_IP_Address";

 // Initializes the espClient
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup_wifi() {
delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
Serial.print(".");
  }
 Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("WiFi connected - ESP IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


 if(topic=="home/office/esp1/gpio2"){
  Serial.print("Changing GPIO 2 to ");
  if(messageTemp == "1"){
//    digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, HIGH);
    Serial.print("On");
  }
  else if(messageTemp == "0"){
  //  digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, LOW);
    Serial.print("Off");
  }
  }
Serial.println();
}


void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");  

     client.subscribe("home/office/esp1/gpio2");
    } 
  else 
 {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
     Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
   }
}
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
   }


void loop() {

   if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
   }
  client.loop();
  }
```

Code for Arduino UNO

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(12, HIGH);

 String messageTemp;
 }

 void callback(String topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
   Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
   Serial.print(topic);
   Serial.print(". Message: ");
    String messageTemp;

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     Serial.print((char)message[i]);
      messageTemp += (char)message[i];
    }
  Serial.println();

 }
 void loop ()
{
  if  (Serial.available()){
   char topic = Serial.read();
  {

    if (topic=="home/office/esp1/gpio2")
  {
       Serial.print("Changing GPIO 2 to ");
      if(messageTemp == "1"){
        digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
        Serial.print("On");
      }
      else if(messageTemp == "0")
       {
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
       Serial.print("Off");
     }

}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

ESP code doesn't look the whole source code you provided. In case of Arduino UNO, if you're intending to use `messageTemp` as a global variable, then you need to declare it only one time outside of functions. In the above code, you declared it twice in `setup()` and `callback()`, then those are considered as local variables. Even in `loop()`, there's no declaration, this should create the compile error.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I had no compile error when I change  in the condition   if (topic=="home/office/esp1/gpio2")  to if (topic=='home/office/esp1/gpio2')